# Calculation and construction of two dimensional array with nested loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to do a calculation with Python. I want to yield a 20*20 array with a nested loop. I do not know if I am in the right direction, but here is my code:

```
w = 1.5
m = 0.556
E = np.linspace(15.4, 4.0, num=20)
u = np.linspace(0.29, 0.79, num=20)
Q = 0

for j in E:
    for i in u:
        Q = E * ( m / 1 + m ) * (1 - (w**2)/((w + u)**2)),

print Q
```

The loop does not produce the 20*20 array. How can I make it work properly?

Comment: Whilst easy to guess, it wouldn't hurt if you included the imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want `Q` to be your final 20x20 array. One key point with Numpy is that you should avoid `for` loops whenever possible as they are much slower than vectorised array operations. There are faster ways to build the 2D array from `E` and `u`.

The main problem in the code is that the line `Q = E * ( m / 1 + m ) * (1 - (w**2)/((w + u)**2))` is actually just multiplying two length 20 arrays together element-wise 400 times, each time producing the same length 20 array `Q`.

That is, we have two length 20 arrays:

```
>>> (E *  ( m / 1 + m ))
array([ 17.1248,  16.4576,  15.7904,  15.1232,  14.456 ,  13.7888,
        13.1216,  12.4544,  11.7872,  11.12  ,  10.4528,   9.7856,
         9.1184,   8.4512,   7.784 ,   7.1168,   6.4496,   5.7824,
         5.1152,   4.448 ])

>>> (1 - (w**2)/((w + u)**2))
array([ 0.29777473,  0.31797577,  0.33731751,  0.35584798,  0.37361193,
        0.39065107,  0.40700429,  0.42270793,  0.43779594,  0.45230007,
        0.46625008,  0.47967384,  0.49259748,  0.50504555,  0.51704109,
        0.52860578,  0.53976   ,  0.55052296,  0.56091274,  0.5709464 ])
```

and multiplying them element-wise with `*` just produces this:

```
>>> E * ( m / 1 + m ) * (1 - (w**2)/((w + u)**2))
array([ 5.09933263,  5.2331181 ,  5.32637834,  5.38156012,  5.40093407,
        5.38660945,  5.34054752,  5.26457365,  5.16038825,  5.02957682,
        4.87361888,  4.69389633,  4.49170089,  4.26824095,  4.02464786,
        3.76198161,  3.48123612,  3.18334398,  2.86918086,  2.53956957])
```

Instead, to turn these two length 20 arrays into the required 20x20 array, you could replace the `for` loops with the following vectorised operation:

```
>>> np.multiply.outer((E * ( m / 1 + m )), (1 - (w**2)/((w + u)**2)))
# the 20x20 array
```

Here the `outer` method of the `multiply` ufunc is used to create the new 20x20 array.